# Getting the nth row of a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following string:

```
BAXH14#cote href="nego_cotes_in_en.php?symbol=BAX&amp;instrument=BAXH14#cote">14 MAR</A></TD>
<TD>98.620</TD>
<TD>98.630</TD>
<TD>98.620</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>33,568</TD>
<TD>6,071</TD><
```

I would like to retrieve the 3rd row as in 98.620. The numbers in this string will change everyday so any help would be great.

Comment: how are you consuming this data? where is it from? Some more details please.

Comment: i just basically got the html off a site and then reduced it to the string shown above...reason i took the html off the site was to get the number shown in the 3rd row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using VBA this will do the trick - just set str to your string

```
Sub test()
Dim str As String
Dim n As Integer

n = 3

str = "testData<TD>98.620</TD><TD>98.630</TD><TD>98.620</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>33,568</TD><TD>6,071</TD>"
subSTR = str
For i = 1 To n
    If Not (InStr(1, subSTR, "<TD>") = 0) Then
        subSTR = Right(subSTR, Len(subSTR) - InStr(1, subSTR, "<TD>") - 3)
    Else
        subSTR = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

finalStr = Left(subSTR, InStr(1, subSTR, "</TD>") - 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

most straightforward way if it is all one string and not a file you are parsing or across multiple rows is to use the following. Assumes string is in Range("A1") of Sheet1.

```
Dim dataSplit() As String
Dim returnData As String

dataSplit = Split(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value2, "</TD>")

returnData = Right$(dataSplit(2), Len(dataSplit(2)) - 5)
```

Comment: +1. Good practice to use the string function `Right$` rather than the variant `Right`

Answer (score 1):

Using Mid (string, start, length) and find (what, where, startpos) you can skip two line feeds - char (10) and set length to the difference between the second and third line feed position like this:-

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1,1)+1),FIND(CHAR(10),A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1,1)+1)+1)-FIND(CHAR(10),A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1,1)+1))
```

Where A1 is assumed to contain your string. If you need to treat  as end of line marker then replace all the char (10) with "".

Elegant? Of course not!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to break up the string into an array using the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function.  This takes a string and prints the 3rd item in the debug window.  Like this...

```
Sub split_td()
    Dim values() As String
    Dim sourceString As String
    Dim result As String

    ' get your source data here
    sourceString = "<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3 - pick me!</td><td>4</td>"

    'break it into an array of strings
    values = Split(sourceString, "<td>")

    'tidy up the end tag
    result = Replace(values(3), "</td>", "")

    Debug.Print values(3)
End Sub
```

If you don't mind an extra column in your sheet then you can do something like this...

```
A------------------------     B----------------------------------------------------------

                              <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3 - pick me!</td><td>4</td>
=SEARCH("<td>", B$1)    
=SEARCH("</td>",B$1)        =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B$1,A2,A3-A2),"/",""),"<td>","")
=SEARCH("</td>",B$1,A3+1)       =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B$1,A3,A4-A3),"/",""),"<td>","")
=SEARCH("</td>",B$1,A4+1)       =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B$1,A4,A5-A4),"/",""),"<td>","")
(etc)
```

Which then puts the points for the text operations in column A and does the extraction in column B.